# Using dispatch_queue while fetching Tweets from Twitter in iOS application

Tags: ios, multithreading

In my iOS application I'm fetching tweets from Twitter in Utility class and then update the main class UITableView (with cell showing individual tweets). Below is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *tweetsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



+ (NSMutableArray *)getTweetStatus:(NSString *)myData{
ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = 
[store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue", NULL);
[store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType 
                 withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                      dispatch_sync(myCustomQueue, ^{
                     if (!granted) {
                         // The user rejected your request 
                         NSLog(@"User rejected access to the account.");
                     } 
                     else {
                         // Grab the available accounts
                         NSArray *twitterAccounts = 
                         [store accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

                         if ([twitterAccounts count] > 0) {
                             // Use the first account for simplicity 
                             ACAccount *account = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

                             // Now make an authenticated request to our endpoint
                             NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                             [params setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

                             //  The endpoint that we wish to call
                             NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];

                             //  Build the request with our parameter 
                             TWRequest *request = 
                             [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                                                 parameters:params 
                                              requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

                             // Attach the account object to this request
                             [request setAccount:account];

                             [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                                 dispatch_sync(myCustomQueue, ^{
                                 if (!responseData) {
                                      // inspect the contents of error 
                                      NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                  } 
                                  else {
                                      NSError *jsonError;
                                      NSMutableArray *tweets =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];            
                                      if (tweets) {                          
                                          // at this point, we have an object that we can parse
                                          NSLog(@"%@", tweets);
                                      }
                                      else { 
                                          // inspect the contents of jsonError
                                          NSLog(@"%@", jsonError);
                                      }
                                      [tweetsArray addObjectsFromArray:tweets];

                                  }
                                 });
                              }];

                         }
                     }
    });
    }];
     return tweetsArray; 
    }
```

The problem is that I don't want to "return tweetsArray" until I get the response (i.e. get response from TWRequest performRequestWithHandler method which add tweets response into "tweetsArray") and for this I placed "dispatch_sync" at two places:

1. In `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType`
2. In `[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)`

But I'm not able to do so by this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your code to something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // put you twitter request here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self changeMyInterfaceMethod: tweetsArray];

    });
});
```

Comment: Ok.but this method is defined in Utility class which i called from my main class. And the scenario is something like this that i cant call [myTableView reload] method . I have to wait untill i get tweet response. I already tried dispatch_async but [return tweetsArray]; calls immediatly causing table to load with no data and i get the response tweets after sometime which is of no use as i say i cant reload my tableView thats why i have to wait untill i get the tweet response and then load the table by returning this "tweetsArray" to main class

Comment: You probably need to change your method getTweetStatus to use blocks or a delegate.

Comment: You cant directly return from a asynchronous method. Instead of returning the value (it will be null because the code still executing) you need to create a delegate that will call your main class method. Here you can see a tutorial about delegates : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/

Comment: i know about delegates but calling method of main class using delegate is of no use because only thing i do in that is reload the tahTableView with tweetsArray but as i said earlier it is not possible due to some reason. All i have to do is return this tweetsArray after getting response any how thats why i use dispatch_sync to wait for response without returning before getting response.

Comment: Overall i think it is all about appropriate use dispatch_queue to acheive desired result. Thats it..i need guidance in this